# How to summon a mob with an item in headslot that has custom model data?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I know how to summon a mob with an item in a slot:

```
/summon minecraft:zombie ~ ~1 ~ {
    ArmorItems:[
        {},{},{},{
            id:"minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick",
            Count:1
        }]
}
```

I also know how to summon an item with custom model data:

`/give @s minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick{CustomModelData:100001}`

But how do you combine both? I've tried:

```
/summon minecraft:zombie ~ ~1 ~ {
    ArmorItems:[
        {},{},{},{
            id:"minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick{CustomModelData:100001}",
            Count:1
        }]
}
```

But that didn't work. Even though it was a "valid" command. I'm doing this in 1.14.4 btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. This would be the correct way to do it:

```
/summon minecraft:zombie ~ ~1 ~ {
    ArmorItems:[
        {},{},{},{
            id:"minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick",
            Count:1b,
            tag:{CustomModelData:100001}
        }]
}
```